# Magento 1.8.1 Product Stock alert emails not sending

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, stock

The Product Stock Alert emails are not sending.

Other emails such as new membership and password chages are sending

Cron appears to be working - the "catalog_product_alert" job is scheduled and appears to be running every minute. The product_alert_stock table shows who is signed up and shows that they have been notified, but they don't get an email.

Looking at email reports in cpanel suggests that no emails have been sent - they are not pending or blocked or successful.

Is there anything else I need to check? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just coming back to answer this in case it helps anyone in the future

It appears the main issue here was the email was falling foul of SpamAssassin on the server. Once we made the email smaller, by removing images and table tags, it seemed to work ok.